# iphone SE gyroscope issue

Tags: iphone, ios, software

I have a problem with my iPhone SE i recently got that and did a factory reset on it the problem is gyroscope sensor seems to have some malfunction but I don't think it'd be a hardware problem because everytime i restart the phone it works ok the raise to wake,screen rotation, compass and... but after a while all of these stop working. I did settings reset,updated from ios 13 to 14.0.1 what else can i do!?

Comment: Is this still under warranty from Apple?  If so, take it back to them to repair or replace it.  If you did an update to the latest OS and there's still a problem, it could be hardware related and that's very difficult to troubleshoot via a Q&A site.

Comment: Hardware issues can be intermittent - it works fine one moment and then malfunctions another.  Given there's no widespread reporting of gyroscope issues like you're describing, it's unlikely to be software as the OS doesn't change from device to device.  If you want to be certain, factory reset your phone (don't restore anything) and see if the problem returns.  If it does - it's hardware.  If it happens after restoring - it's probably an App.

Comment: thanks so then i have to take it for repair and it doesn't have warranty anymore I may have ro take it to some unofficial repair shop because as i know there is no apple store around where i am